# Correct way of Post(HTTP) values from entity c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, controller

So, I am a newbie with entity. I am trying to Post some values, but I cannot get the values of one model class inside of another one. 
If I am thinking about do something wrong, I appreciate any help about the correct way.

Model class 1 (resultados)

```
public partial class resultados
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public resultados()
    {
        this.respLysholm = new HashSet<respLysholm>();
    }

    public int idResult { get; set; }
    public int perfilPac_idPac { get; set; }
    public int resultado { get; set; }
    public int id_questionario { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime dtRegistro { get; set; }
    //public respLysholm respostasLysholm { get; set; }

    public virtual perfilPac perfilPac { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<respLysholm> respLysholm { get; set; }
}
```

Model class 2 (respLysholm):

```
public partial class respLysholm
{
    public int idPac { get; set; }
    public int resultados_idResult { get; set; }
    public int questao1 { get; set; }
    public int questao2 { get; set; }
    public int questao3 { get; set; }
    public int questao4 { get; set; }
    public int questao5 { get; set; }
    public int questao6 { get; set; }
    public int questao7 { get; set; }
    public int questao8 { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime dtRegistro { get; set; }

}
```

In my controller, I receive a object with values of "resultados" and values of "respLysholm" that is the class inside class "resultados".
I need to send the values of "respLysholm" to the database. Now, just the "resultados" values are going.

```
[HttpPost]
[ResponseType(typeof(resultados))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Postresultados([FromBody]resultados Resultados)
{

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }


    db.resultados.Add(Resultados);
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();

    respLysholm respostas = new respLysholm
    {
        idPac = Resultados.perfilPac_idPac,
        resultados_idResult = Resultados.idResult

    };
    \\this code doesnt work but is what i mean that i need.
    \\db.respLysholm.Add(Resultados.respLysholm);
    \\await db.SaveChangesAsync();

}
```

The body of Post... i want to get all the values of "respostasLysholm".

```
{"idResult":0,"perfilPac_idPac":1,"resultado":14,"id_questionario":1,"dtRegistro":"2017-05-23T23:28:24.916866-03:00",
"respostasLysholm":{"idPac":1,"resultados_idResult":0 ,"questao1":3}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very hard to read because you are not following any of the C# or .NET conventions. What you have is a one-to-many relationship. Here is how you can add items to db in a one-to-many relationship. In this example we have a class that can have many students:

```
var science = new Class();
science.Name = "Sci-101";

science.Students.Add(new Student { Name = "Tom" });
science.Students.Add(new Student { Name = "Jerry" });

using (var dbCtx = new SchoolDBEntities())
{
    // Add the class
    dbCtx.Classes.Add(science);

    // Save whole entity graph to the database.
    // You do not need to save the students separately since they are part
    // of the class. We have already added them to the class so saving the 
    // class will save the students added to the class as well.
    dbCtx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: All of this code was automaticaly generated by VS2017. I did the database and after applied the entity from database. Just this. But the code just do the Post to one table...i need to do in more than one...so, i am thinking about "extract" the values and add to the respective database.

Comment: I edited with the body of Post values. I appreciate if you help me ... thanks

Comment: I did manually, but is so ugly... `respLysholm respostas = new respLysholm
            {
                idPac = Resultados.perfilPac_idPac,
                resultados_idResult = resultados.idResult,
                questao1 = Resultados.respostasLysholm.questao1,
                questao2 = Resultados.respostasLysholm.questao2,
                
            }; `